# Dynamic foregin key like in database

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic, foreign-keys

Is it good idea to have database structure like this? Where in manager table id_item is like foregn key from school or company based on the type of the profile (id_item is school.id or company.id based on type field) Like dynamic variable in programming languages where it don't have a type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well why don't you create an organization table and reference it to the manager. Do you need this level of detail, having two separate entities?

[image: Organization as super entity]

- A manager manages one or more organization.
- An organization is managed by **only one** manager.
- An organization can be a company or school.
- A school has a location as addition.

Comment: I need to, because both company and school tables are connected to different ones, that's only a fraction of actual database.

Comment: Well you can create a (parent) entity like organization. Organization is 1:1 associated with school or company. Therefore you have only one reference to the manager. No type needed.

Comment: How then I should connect organization with two tables, I will need to have the same thing in organization table as in manager.